Setting up PXE to install Linux from TFTP
I am currently in the process of building a PXE/TFTP install server in my network to host a few tools and .iso files - as my first project working with linux. Therefore I am a bit of a noob.
I am using pxelinux and I have already managed to get memtest86 running over the network and managed to get ubuntu 22.04 to download from the web and to install on the machine.
This is my pxelinux.conf:
DEFAULT     menu.c32
MENU TITLE  Installserver
TIMEOUT     100

LABEL       memtest
MENU LABEL  Memtest86+ 
MENU DEFAULT    
LINUX       memtest86+/memtest86+.bin

LABEL       Ubuntu Server over Internet
KERNEL      vmlinuz
INITRD      initrd
APPEND      root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso ignore_uuid

LABEL       Ubuntu Desktop
MENU LABEL  Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop
KERNEL      vmlinuz
INITRD      initrd
APPEND      root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000
LINUX       ISOs/Ubuntu/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

The menu option "Ubuntu Server over Internet" works just fine. "Ubuntu Desktop" just times out after a while and I get the following error in the log:
Apr 25 11:21:37 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: sent /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/default to 10.100.20.141
Apr 25 11:21:37 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: sent /srv/tftp/menu.c32 to 10.100.20.141
Apr 25 11:21:37 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: sent /srv/tftp/libutil.c32 to 10.100.20.141
Apr 25 11:21:37 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: sent /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/default to 10.100.20.141
Apr 25 11:24:42 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: error 0 No error, file close received from 10.100.20.141
Apr 25 11:24:42 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: failed sending /srv/tftp/ISOs/Ubuntu/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso to 10.100.20.141
Apr 25 11:25:08 er-hal-pxe-01 dnsmasq-tftp[757]: sent /srv/tftp/initrd to 10.100.20.141

I guess I have to point the client towards the TFTP server running on the same machine as the PXE server with APPEND, but I really don't know how. Any pointers?
